# How to return reference to locally allocated struct/object? AKA error: `foo` does not live long enough

Tags: pointers, rust

Here's a simplified example of what I'm doing:

```
struct Foo ...
impl io::Read for Foo ...

fn problem<'a>() -> io::Result<&'a mut io::Read> {
    // foo does not live long enough, because it gets allocated on the stack
    let mut foo = Foo{ v: 42 };
    Ok(&mut foo)
}
```

Rust playground is [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=34fe97f924ff004a13ad&version=stable).

Obviously, the problem is that `foo` is allocated on the stack, so if we return a reference to it, the reference outlives the object.

In C, you'd get around this by using `malloc` to allocate the object on the heap, and the caller would need to know to call `free` when appropriate. In a GCed language, this would just work since `foo` would stick around until there are no references to it. Rust is really clever, and kind of in-between, so I'm not sure what my options are.

I think one option would be to return a managed pointer type. Is `Box` the most appropriate? (I found a guide to pointers in rust, but it is way outdated.)

The reason I'm returning a reference is that in reality I need to return any of several structs which implement `Read`. I suppose another option would be to create an enum to wrap each of the possible structs. That would avoid heap allocation, but seems needlessly awkward.

Are there other options I haven't thought of?

Comment: I think you want a *trait object*: `Box<io::Read>`.

Comment: @Shepmaster: please be careful with the terminology around trait objects—`io::Read` is a trait object, `Box<io::Read>` is a boxed trait object. `&mut io::Read` is as much a trait object as `Box<io::Read>`.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan ugh, good point. That's what I get for throwing out a quick comment.

Answer (score 5):

Replacing the reference with a `Box` [compiles successfully](http://is.gd/hORcQw):

```
fn problem<'a>() -> io::Result<Box<io::Read>> {
    let mut foo = Foo{ v: 42 };
    Ok(Box::new(foo))
}
```

Comment: Yes, I mentioned I could use `Box`, but what are the implications/alternatives? Would I need to change everything that uses the result of `problem` to use `Box` too, or can I use a more generic/abstract pointer type?

Comment: @aij: You can borrow the interior of a box with `&*box` (or just `&box`, thanks to `Deref`) to obtain a borrowed pointer from a `Box`.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use static type? Looks like in either C or rust, static variable lasts as long as the program does - even if it's a static local.

http://rustbyexample.com/scope/lifetime/static_lifetime.html

Comment: In my case I can't use a `'static` lifetime, but it is a good option to keep in mind.